# How do I get the screen scaling in FireMonkey?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, c++builder

Using C++ Builder v. 10.2.3, I want to center a TForm that is being resized. To do this, I use the TScreen::WorkArea values. However, running on a system with Windows 10 scaling at 125%, the code doesn't work properly, as the TForm is scaled up. How can I determine if such scaling is occurring, and then adjust accordingly? Is there built in functionality in FireMonkey to do this? I should note that with scaling > 100% in Windows 10, the TForm::TPosition values don't seem to work properly - for example, setting it to ScreenCenter seems to have a similar problem, where it isn't actually centered.

Comment: This is relevant to Delphi, as there might be comparable functionality with C++ Builder and Delphi on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function will return the screen scaling, i.e. 1.25 if you are using 125% scaling on Windows:

```
function GetScreenScale: Single;
var ScreenService: IFMXScreenService;
begin
  Result := 1;
  if TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService (IFMXScreenService, IInterface(ScreenService)) then
    Result := ScreenService.GetScreenScale;
end;
```

Note that on Mac, the only screen scaling possible is 1.0 (non-retina) and 2.0 (retina). However,  on the Mac the values returned by TScreen are already scaled, so no correction is needed.

Comment: Awesome. I will add the C++ Builder equivalent code below.

Comment: I use Delphi 10.3.3. this option does not work on Mac os Catalina . when I set result of scale to 1 . on Retina display it still changes the style and layout. Could you please tell me how can I solve this problem

Comment: so is there anyway to set screen scale on Mac os Catalina

Answer (score 2):

The C++ equivalent of Hans' answer is

```
double GetScreenScale ()
{
    double value = 1.0;
    _di_IFMXScreenService screenService;
    if (TPlatformServices::Current->SupportsPlatformService (__uuidof (IFMXScreenService), &screenService))
        value = screenService->GetScreenScale ();
    return value;
}
```